# Best practice for using a function in different classes

Tags: swift, function, inheritance

I am new in swift and in programming in general. I am working in a project where I have to handle the orientation change from Landscape to Protrait and vice-versa. Every time the orientation change I have to change the value of different variables such as NSLayoutconstraint, font sizes... I wrote this changes in a function

```
func updateValuesForAppropriateOrientations ()
{

  if ipadPortrait()
  {
  //update variables for ipad portrait
  }
  else if ipadLandscape()
  {
  //update variables for ipad landscape
  }

{
```

everything is working fine but I am using this function in a lot of different ViewControllers and I am re-writing it every time. Is it the right way to do it or shall I use inheritance r something else? But the variables are different in every ViewController so I don see how would inheritance help. What are the best practice and how can I make my code cleaner is my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way in which we are encouraged to do this now is to use the viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. This is part of the UIContentContainer protocol to which all UIViewControllers adhere. Rather than think about screen orientations the idea is that you should instruct your view controllers to take action whenever their root view size is set to change. To your point about having to rewrite your function for every view controller in your project, this is surplus to requirements as viewWillTransitionToSize is automatically called on any change that might concern the viewController. Hope that helps.

Details at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/

Answer (score 0):

If you make all the variables to have the same names, then you can inject common functionality via default protocol implementation.

An example:

```
protocol Rotatable {
    var height: Int { get set }
    var width: Int { get set }
    mutating func rotate()
}

extension Rotatable {
    mutating func rotate() {
        let temp = height
        height = width
        width = temp
    }
}

class Foo {
    var height = 1
    var width = 2
}

struct Bar {
    var height = 10
    var width = 20
}

extension Foo: Rotatable { }
extension Bar: Rotatable { }

var foo = Foo()
var bar = Bar()

print("Foo is \(foo.height)x\(foo.width)") // Foo is 1x2
print("Bar is \(bar.height)x\(bar.width)") // Bar is 10x20

foo.rotate()
bar.rotate()

print("Foo is \(foo.height)x\(foo.width)") // Foo is 2x1
print("Bar is \(bar.height)x\(bar.width)") // Bar is 20x10
```